# enumitem: Get rid of extra space between label and content in inline list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I use `\setlist{wide}` with the package `enumitem` to unindent a subsequent line in an item in vertical (normal) lists. This no indentation rule is a publisher guideline that I cannot change.

The problem is when I write an *inline* list extra space between the label and the content of an item sometimes emerges. (Please see the MWE: there is apparent extra space between "1." and "The first thing...".)

How can I get rid of this extra space?

MWE:

[image: extra space example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{wide}

\begin{document}

This is an inline enumeration. 
\begin{enumerate*}
    \item The first thing to enumerate. There should not be excessive space
    between the number and the content.
    \item The second thing to enumerate.
    \item The third thing to enumerate.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is reproducible with `article`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for noticing. I changed to `scrartcl`.

Comment: Why not `article`? And do you really need to use `\setlist{wide}`? The output looks fine without this option.

Comment: @frougon on the other hand why should `wide` affect inline lists? This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @daleif I'm not claiming the opposite. :-P

Comment: Report it to the author at http://www.texnia.com/enumitem.html.

Comment: @frougon I use `\setlist{wide}` per publisher requirement. I thought `scrartcl` was a replacement for `article` - not that it matters for this problem.

Comment: @FangJing Unless the problem is specific to a particular class, better stay with standard classes when preparing a minimal working example for this site. Thanks.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for the suggestion. I do not find a bug report function or contact on the website.

Comment: See the contact link on the right side of the page. In there is a mailto form, there `enumitem` is one of the package options (Javier manages several packages)

Comment: According to the manual, with `wide`, “the items look like ordinary paragraphs”, so this setting is not meant for `inline` lists. Just define `inline` lists with `\newlist`, and restrict `wide`to those list types requiring it.

Comment: @JavierBezos I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Javier Bezos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735/javier-bezos)'s comment, I put together the following solution (see the MWE below). The `wide` list option is only applied to `enumerate` and `itemize`. Two inline lists, `inlineenum` and `inlineitem` are defined.

MWE:

[image: solution]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlineenum}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist*[inlineenum]{mode=unboxed,label=(\arabic*)}

\newlist{inlineitem}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist*[inlineitem]{label=\textbullet}

\setlist[enumerate,itemize]{wide}

\begin{document}

This is an inline enumeration. 
\begin{inlineenum}
    \item The first thing to enumerate. There should not be excessive space
    between the number and the content.
    \item The second thing to enumerate.
    \item The third thing to enumerate.
\end{inlineenum}

And this is an inline itemization. 
\begin{inlineitem}
    \item The first thing to itemize. There should not be excessive space
    between the number and the content.
    \item The second thing to itemize.
    \item The third thing to itemize.
\end{inlineitem}

\end{document}
```

*Remark.* If you use a document class that already implements "wide" vertical lists by default and you do not need the extensive features of `enumitem`, you may just use the `paralist` package to implement the inline lists `inparaenum` and `inparaitem` with

> `\usepackage[olditem, oldenum]{paralist}`

Answer (score 4):

Inline lists do not use  the same horizontal parameters as usual lists – they use `afterlabel`, `\itemjoin` and `\itemjoin*`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

This is an inline enumeration.
\begin{enumerate*}[afterlabel=\hspace{2pt}, itemjoin=\quad]
    \item The first thing to enumerate. There should not be excessive space
    between the number and the content.
    \item The second thing to enumerate.
    \item The third thing to enumerate.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do need to retain `\setlist{wide}` for formatting vertical (normal) lists per publisher guidelines. I'm updating the question to make this clear. If I add `\setlist{wide}` to your code, the extra space appears again.

Comment: Yes, I've just seen that, and even iwithout `\setlist`, just writing `\begin[enumerate[wide]` for a specific normal  list before. Note there exist other packages which manage inline lists, so you might remove the `[inline]  option until the problem is solved.

Comment: It looks like a bug, in my opinion.

Comment: That's probably true. Thank you!